# Spring base repository implementation doesn't affect on inherited interfaces

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to create a base generic repository interface and then by implementing this interface by a class I would like other interfaces that implemented base interface work with implemented class

here is the base interface:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface Base<T>{
T getFoo();
}
```

here is the class implements the base repository:

```
public class BaseImple<T> implements Base<T>{
public T getFoo(){
//do some stuff
return t;
}
}
```

here is the first repository:

```
@Repository
public interface A extends Base<FOO>{
}
```

here is the second repository:

```
@Repository
public interface B extends Base<BAR>{
}
```

but when I auto wire interface B then I get error:

`no qualifying bean of type B`

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface Base<T>{
T getFoo();
}
```

```
@Repository
public class BaseImple<T> implements Base<T>{
public T getFoo(){
//do some stuff
return t;
   }
}
```

```
public interface A extends Base<FOO>{
}
```

```
public interface B extends Base<BAR>{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are creating only Interfaces which can't be instantiated. There is no place Spring can find an Object / Bean for that Repository so try to have a implementation class which extends your Repository as shown by @hmaz or extend [CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) or [JpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) in your Interface for Spring to provide implementation.